# Display Select Content with Array in DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, dompdf

i have in my php a dynamic form with select tag, when i try export the form with DOMPDF, He display only the first Dynamic Form and ignore the others.
See my code bellow;

```html
 <div class="panel-heading"><b>Interrupções</b></div>
  <div class="intcont">
    <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select required="" class="form-control" id="interrupcao" name="interrupcao[]">
          <option value="N/A">Motivo</option>
          <option value="Indisponibilidade de equipamentos">Indisponibilidade de equipamentos</option>
          <option value="Indisponibilidade de Área de teste">Indisponibilidade de Área de teste</option>
          <option value="Outros (Descrever em Comentários)">Outros (Descrever em Comentários)</option>
        </select>
        <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="inicioint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Início"/>
        <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="terminoint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Término"/>
        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- copy of input fields group -->
    <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select required="" class="form-control" id="interrupcao" name="interrupcao[]">
          <option value="N/A">Motivo</option>
          <option value="Indisponibilidade de equipamentos">Indisponibilidade de equipamentos</option>
          <option value="Indisponibilidade de Área de teste">Indisponibilidade de Área de teste</option>
          <option value="Outros (Descrever em Comentários)">Outros (Descrever em Comentários)</option>
        </select>
        <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="inicioint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Início"/>
        <input required="" value="N/A" type="text" name="terminoint[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Término"/>
        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And a snnipet of my php code with $dompdf->load_html('...'); :
Command to get all arrays: for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($_POST['interrupcao']); $i++).

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>INTERRUPÇÕES</th>
            <th>Início</th>
            <th>Término</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$_POST['interrupcao'][$i].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['inicioint'][$i].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['terminoint'][$i].'</td>           
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used any `form` tag..

- First add `Form` tags..
- Now change id and name of different input elements.Two input elements must not have same name and id tags..

Comment: The problem is that I tried without the DOMPDF and worked fine in displaying all the arrays.

Comment: Ok ! I m glad you got that but above said things are mistakes in your code..Hope you knew.

Comment: Thanks, but my error continues, because without dompdf it works, however I need to use the arrays inside Dompdf.

Comment: No worries ..ask here if you stuck on something.